# How can i Bind data in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, cascadingdropdown

Here im using Mvc Here i wan 2 bind data in dropdownList.For Binding data i Created a Hybrid class

```
public class HybridClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Country> GetCountry { get; set; }
    }
```

This Class I Binded in my ctrl as

**HybridClass  Objhybrid=new HybridClass  ();**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Crude()
            {
                IEnumerable<Employee> emp = await Task.Run(() => ObjRepo.GetEmployee());
                IEnumerable<Country> cntry = await Task.Run(() => ObjRepo.GetCountrylist());
                Objhybrid.GetEmployee = emp;
                Objhybrid.GetCountry = cntry;
                return View(Objhybrid);
```

Here i How Can i bind Data in DropdonListFor  Here im Getting Data

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(cnt=>cnt.GetCountry,Model=>Model.)
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `GetCountry` is). Refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for how to generate a dropdownlist

Comment: @StephenMuecke  did u have any Other Idea so that i can finish my work

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank Soo much Its Working